# How to play sound after calling recorder and than animation start and than play sound?

Tags: iphone, animation, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I have to task to develop an application which plays sound after user blow candles and than the sound should play. For blowing candle I have used AVAudioRecorder that catch user blow and than its starts animation of stopped candles and than it should start to play the song but its not playing the song. I have stored song locally.(in my application)

for AVAudioRecorder

```
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],  AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
        nil];
    NSError *error1;

    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url1 settings:settings error:&error1];
```

animation images starts and after that song should be play.

```
imageView1.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"can6.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"can7.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"can8.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"can9.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"can10.png"],nil];
    [imageView1 setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    imageView1.animationDuration=0.7;
    [imageView1 startAnimating];
    [recorder stop];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
              initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
             [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:xyz song ofType:nil]]
             error:nil];
    NSLog(@"music play-%@",xyz song);
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
```

All codes are working properly only sound is not playing.
I get candle stop animation starts but I can't here the song. Although the above sound play code works in another view perfectly and its plays the song but it's not playing the song here. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the result of [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:xyz song ofType:nil] is not nil. I think the problem might be passing nil for type. For example, if your song is HappyBirthday.mp3, you should call

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HappyBirthday" ofType:@"mp3"];
```

Comment: i have tried like this but its not working perfectly. my mean for xyz song is that its one kind of NSString *xyz song. & as i told the player(same code for player) is going to be played perfectly in other view where i am not calling recorder and animation.